# EF Core and Saving Async

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, .net-core

I'm testing out a bulk import using EF Core and trying to save asynchronously.

I'm trying to add 100 entities at a time and then asynchronously save and repeat until they are all saved.  I occasionally get a PK error because it tries to add two entities with the same id to the database.  None of the entities being added have an id set, the ids are sequences that are auto generated.

The code:

```
public async Task<bool> BulkAddAsync(IEnumerable<VehicleCatalogModel> models)
{
    _dbContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        var entities = models.Select(ToEntity);
        _dbContext.Set<VehicleCatalog>().AddRange(entities);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(0, ex, "An Error occurred during the import");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am calling the method in an xunit test that generates a list of test data and calls the import

```
var result = manager.BulkAddAsync(modelsToAdd.AsEnumerable());
var counter = 0;
while (!result.IsCompleted && counter < 10)
{
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
    counter++;
}
Assert.True(result.IsCompleted && result.Result);
```

It should hold up the execution after 100 entities have been added until they are saved, and then add more but I am still occasionally getting this error.  Is there something else I need to add to get this to work correctly?  Or a better method of bulk insert?

Comment: Why are you not using AddRange and just **one** SaveChanges?

Comment: `Or a better method of bulk insert?` => [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better alternative for very large data sets.

Comment: Show how you call that code - as shown it will only save one at a time.

Comment: `the Ids are sequences that are auto generated` <= so probably a race condition. Why are you generating the sequence, most databases have built in mechanisms to do this like `identity` in sql-server. To know more you must supply the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Edited to include the full method and the test.  I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: The issue is a race condition and your not shown `ToEntity` method. Use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) instead of trying to generate your own identifier, this will mitigate the Exception (sql error) you are getting.

Comment: @igor I leave the Id field in the entity blank.  EF has the Identity columns generated on save using SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was getting much better performance doing smaller sets and saving instead of attaching a couple thousand entities to the context and once and then saving

Comment: Then the issue is one of these things: 1) there is no issue with your primary key at all, you did not read the exception correctly and you should post the Exception and all it's details in your question. 2) Your compiled and executing code differs from the code you are viewing 3) the database table definition was not updated and the PK was never set to Identity.

Comment: Your test should `await` the `BulkAddAsync` call.